# Setting a player pref key results in setting all of them Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, key

When I try to use `PlayerPrefsManager.SetFood()` it sets all of the player pref strings. So if I do `PlayerPrefsManager.SetFood(Monday, Bread)`, it sets `MONDAY_KEY`, `TUESDAY_KEY`, `WEDNESDAY_KEY`, etc to `Bread`. Can someone please point out my error?

Edit: I know that it's all `if` statements in the `SetFood` function (instead of `else if` statements), but due to the fact that 2 or more instances of the function could be called at the same time I replaced all of the `else if` statements (I'm not sure if that's the correct wording).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPrefsManager : MonoBehaviour {
    const string MONDAY_KEY = "null";
    const string TUESDAY_KEY = "null";
    const string WEDNESDAY_KEY = "null";
    const string THURSDAY_KEY = "null";
    const string FRIDAY_KEY = "null";
    const string SATURDAY_KEY = "null";
    const string SUNDAY_KEY = "null";

    public static string GetFood (string Day){
        if (Day == "Monday") {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetString (MONDAY_KEY);
        } else if (Day == "Tuesday") {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetString (TUESDAY_KEY);
        } else if (Day == "Wednesday") {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetString (WEDNESDAY_KEY);
        } else if (Day == "Thursday") {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetString (THURSDAY_KEY);
        } else if (Day == "Friday") {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetString (FRIDAY_KEY);
        } else if (Day == "Saturday") {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetString (SATURDAY_KEY);
        } else if (Day == "Sunday") {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetString (SUNDAY_KEY);
        } else{
            return "Day out of range";
        }
    }

    public static void SetFood (string Day, string Food){
        if (Day == "Monday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (MONDAY_KEY, Food); 
        } if (Day == "Tuesday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (TUESDAY_KEY, Food);
        } if (Day == "Wednesday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (WEDNESDAY_KEY, Food);
        } if (Day == "Thursday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (THURSDAY_KEY, Food);
        } if (Day == "Friday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (FRIDAY_KEY, Food);
        } if (Day == "Saturday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (SATURDAY_KEY, Food);
        } if (Day == "Sunday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (SUNDAY_KEY, Food);
        } if (!(Day == "Monday") || (Day == "Tuesday") || (Day == "Wednesday") || (Day == "Thursday") || (Day == "Friday") || (Day == "Saturday") || (Day == "Sunday")) {
            Debug.LogError ("Day out of range");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Another thing you can try is put a return statement at the end of each if. E.g. `if (Day == "Monday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (MONDAY_KEY, Food); 
            return; 
        }`

Comment: I have done a Debug.Log and the end of each statement. It didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

All your keys have same value i.e. "null". That's why you get the same value no matter if the const var name is different. The actual value should be different.  Give it unique value like this.

```
 const string MONDAY_KEY = "monday_key";
 const string TUESDAY_KEY = "tuesday_key";
 const string WEDNESDAY_KEY = "wednesday_key";
 const string THURSDAY_KEY = "thursday_key";
 const string FRIDAY_KEY = "friday_key";
 const string SATURDAY_KEY = "saturday_key";
 const string SUNDAY_KEY = "sunday_key";
```

Also, a better way to write SetFood method would be like this. Check for validity before setting PlayerPrefs and return if not valid. Notice I have removed the '!' operator from the beginning of your if statement and used '!=' instead in individual condition elements. Moreover its perfectly fine to use `if else` statements even in static functions. Don't worry about it being called at the same time. Unity makes sure its called one by one unless you are implenting multi-threading. ;)

```
public static void SetFood (string Day, string Food){       
         if ((Day != "Monday") || (Day != "Tuesday") || (Day != "Wednesday") || (Day != "Thursday") || (Day != "Friday") || (Day != "Saturday") || (Day != "Sunday") ) {
            Debug.LogError ("Day out of range");
            return;
        }

        if (Day == "Monday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (MONDAY_KEY, Food); 
        } else if (Day == "Tuesday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (TUESDAY_KEY, Food);
        } else if (Day == "Wednesday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (WEDNESDAY_KEY, Food);
        } else if (Day == "Thursday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (THURSDAY_KEY, Food);
        } else if (Day == "Friday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (FRIDAY_KEY, Food);
        } else if (Day == "Saturday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (SATURDAY_KEY, Food);
        } else if (Day == "Sunday") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString (SUNDAY_KEY, Food);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tysm! It's fixed!